# Spring-Data-Jpa use @Query Caused by: com.alibaba.druid.sql.parser.ParserException

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I use data-jpa query return entity when use @Query

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MzContentArenaDTO implements Serializable {


    private Integer id;


    private Integer arenaId;


    private Integer contentId;

    private LocalDateTime createDate;



    public MzContentArenaDTO(Integer id, Integer arenaId, Integer contentId) {
        this.id = id;
        this.arenaId = arenaId;
        this.contentId = contentId;
    }

}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mz_content_arena")
public class MzContentArena {
   
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    private Integer arenaId;

    private Integer contentId;
}
```

```
@Repository
public interface MzArenaRepository extends JpaRepository<MzArena,Long> {

    @Query(value = "select new com.qiguliuxing.dts.db.entity.MzContentArenaDTO(car.id,car.arena_id,car.content_id) from MzContentArena car where car.arena_id=?1",nativeQuery = true)
    public List<MzContentArenaDTO> findMzArenaByName3(String id);
}
```

[image]

I donot know what happen
I donot know what happen
I donot know what happen
use @Query return result to MzContentArenaDTO Entit

Comment: You have the attribute "nativeQuery = true", but your query doesn't look like a native query at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the attribute "nativeQuery = true", but your query doesn't look like a native query at all.

That is why you get the exception, the parser fails to parse this incorrect syntax.

A native query would be usual SQL, something like :

`@Query(value = "select car.id, car.arena_id, car.content_id from mz_content_arena car where car.arena_id=?1", nativeQuery = true)`